# I am using rasp bery pi to connetct vision tek external modem

Tags: linux

I am using rasp bery pi to connect vision tek external modem ...
for that i am using wvdial as a application program to dial ....
I am able to run AT commands through another application program ... 
but if i am going to ping google.com, its showing "ping: unknown host google.com".. 
and i have put below the result for starting wvdial...
help me out to connect modem that i should use Internet access by modem
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo wvdial...

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot set information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Fri Jul  3 23:17:28 2015
--> Pid of pppd: 2513
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: p�;
--> pppd: p�;
--> pppd: p�;
--> pppd: p�;
--> pppd: p�;
--> local  IP address 100.73.194.38
--> pppd: p�;
--> remote IP address 192.200.1.21
--> pppd: p�;
--> primary   DNS address 125.22.47.102
--> pppd: p�;
--> secondary DNS address 125.22.47.103
--> pppd: p�;
```

Comment: Does the pppd program issue a `route add default ...` command? You could check the current route table with `route`

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions related to programming.  This question would be better off on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: i have checked route to show routing table

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    UseIface
0.0.0.0             10.1.1.1         0.0.0.0                 UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0           0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
192.200.1.21    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255   UH    0      0        0 ppp0

Comment: and i have added gateway as a default  : sudo route add default gw 192.200.1.21..... and it doesn't face any issue....

Comment: Is it  issue of username  and password ...????

Comment: but after, querying only "sudo route add default 192.200.1.21"  without gateway then it's flashing "SIOCADDRT: No such device"